# Rails / Ruby: Getting a subset of objects after a .find query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
```

Video has a parameter called description. I would like to get a subset of @video where :description is empty. I'm sure there's an inline .each type statement that would do it but have no idea how.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, in your example code you're only retrieving one record. To retrieve *all* records, you'd have to call:

```
@videos = Video.all
```

To get a subset, it depends how you want to do it. You can either do it when you're querying the database:

```
# Rails 2
@videos = Video.find(:all, :conditions => ['description = ? OR description IS NULL', ''])

# Rails 3
@videos = Video.where('description = ? OR description IS NULL', '')
```

Or, you could partition your `@videos` array using a Ruby method:

```
# Find all our videos
@videos = Video.all

# And then pick the ones where the description attribute is blank
@videos_with_blank_description = @videos.select { |v| v.description.blank? }
```

`Array#select` is a method in `Enumerable` which iterates through an array and returns the elements where the block argument evaluates to True:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001488

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
#Rails 2.3: 
Video.all(:conditions => {:description => nil})

#Rails 3:   
Video.where(:description => nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@videos = Video.all(:conditions => [ "description IS NULL OR description = ?", '' ])
```

That should pull all the videos with null or empty description. Good luck!