# Parsing an array of objects by attributes in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible to parse an array of objects to select them by attribute? I have a situation where I need to display all objects of a model grouped by an attribute on the index page.  What I had been doing in my controller is this...

```
#xx_controller.rb

@group1 = City.where(:population => 'big')
@group2 = City.where(:population => 'medium')
@group3 = City.where(:population => 'small')
```

But I'd prefer to do something like this in the controller...

```
@cities = City.all
```

And in my view something along the lines of a query, rather than prepackaged instance variables -

```
@cities.where....
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I like the 1 database call way, but then I'd put them in groups in the controller. I'd rename the groups to something like `@big_cities, @medium_cities, @small_cities` also

Comment: So I found the answer elsewhere on stack...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269108/rails-ruby-getting-a-subset-of-objects-after-a-find-query

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind loading everything at once from the database, you can do:

```
@cities = City.all.group_by(&:population)
```

Which returns a hash whose keys are the possible values for the `population` attribute.
Then, on your view, you can access the cities on each 'group' by doing `@cities['small']`, `@cities['medium']` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
@cities = City.all

small_cities = @cities.select { |city| city.population == 'small' }
medium_cities = @cities.select { |city| city.population == 'medium' }
big_cities = @cities.select { | city| city.population == 'big' }
```